# localhost domain bypasses /etc/hosts file

Tags: virtualhost, mac-osx, localhost

I'm trying to create a development environment with `.localhost` as the FQDN.

I'm using [Local by Flywheel](https://local.getflywheel.com/) which is basically MAMP, its a GUI which lets me create vagrant boxes. I can create a site such as `example.dev` and point it to my local IP address in the `/etc/hosts` file and it works great:

```
192.168.95.100 example.dev
```

And I can change it to something else like `example.test` and it still works great:

```
192.168.95.100 example.test
```

If I change it to `.localhost` I get a 403 forbidden error.

```
192.168.95.100 example.localhost
```

There are no other records in my `/etc/hosts` file. I'm trying to work out at what stage the domain is routed somewhere else.

What would prevent the localhost domain from mapping to the correct URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The `localhost` is already reserved as a *Special-Use Domain Name* ([RFC 6761, 6.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761#section-6.3)).

> The domain `localhost.` and any names falling within `.localhost.` are special in the following ways: - -
>
> 3. Name resolution APIs and libraries SHOULD recognize `localhost`
>    names as special and SHOULD always return the IP loopback address
>    for address queries and negative responses for all other query
>    types.  Name resolution APIs SHOULD NOT send queries for
>    `localhost` names to their configured caching DNS server(s).

You may have confused this with `.local`, widely used in private networks and reserved *special-use domain name* for Multicast DNS (mDNS) in [RFC 6762](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762). When using `.local`, try avoid resolving those names using global DNS. Using [`.local` in Active Directory](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810122929/http://www.mdmarra.com/2012/11/why-you-shouldnt-use-local-in-your.html) is a classic example of very bad implementation causing unnecessary queries to L *root name server*.

Comment: In summary, make up whatever `.test` you want,  or register a domain and use that namespace, like  `wwwdev.example.com`.  Anything else may not work as expected in the DNS.